# WooCommerce:Custom product template - Pagination isn't working

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress, woocommerce

all products are displayed. **`"posts_per_page"`** is not working. I try to limit products to 12 by page, but it shows all products.

Looks like my code is fine, but it isn't working.

Whats wrong with my code? 
Can someone enlighten me, please?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $meta_query   = array();
    $meta_query[] = array('key' => '_visibility','value' => array('visible', 'catalog'),'compare' => 'IN');
    $meta_query[] = array('key' => '_stock_status','value' => 'instock','compare' => '=');
    if($min_price !='' && $max_price !=''){
        $meta_query[] = array('key' => '_price','value' => array($min_price, $max_price),'compare' => 'BETWEEN','type' => 'NUMERIC');
    }
    if($orderbym != '')
    {
      $mkey = '_price';
    }
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'      => 10,
        'paged'               => $paged,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'orderby'             => $orderby,
        'order'               => $order,
        'posts_per_page'      => -1,
        'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
        'meta_key'            => $mkey,
        'tax_query'           => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy'      => 'product_type',
              'field'         => 'slug',
              'terms'         => 'bundle',
            ),
            $product_catar
        ),
    );
    global $woocommerce_loop;
    $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $query_args));
    $columns   = '2';
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;
    ob_start();
    if($products->have_posts()){
      woocommerce_product_loop_start();
      while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
          $products->the_post();
          wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
      }
      woocommerce_product_loop_end();
   }else{
      _e( 'No product matching your criteria.' );
   }
   woocommerce_reset_loop();
   wp_reset_postdata();
   echo '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind is that the filter is maybe overwriting the query args. See what you get by doing

```
var_dump(apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $query_args)) ;
```

My guess is you'll get different query args

Comment: but i try this code also its also not working "$products = new WP_Query($query_args);".

Comment: After closer look you have 'posts_per_page'  argument twice in the array, first with value 10, five lines bellow with value - 1..

Comment: Thanks mate that is problem.